# Unable to create a new app with Angular 10

Tags: angular-cli

I tried to create a new app using *Angular 10*. I waited for hours but did not get installed. What might be the problem?

node -v
v12.18.1

C:\Users\DELL>npm -v
6.14.5
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.18.1

```sh
CREATE my-app1/angular.json (3574 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/package.json (1283 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/README.md (1023 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/tsconfig.json (489 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/tslint.json (3125 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/karma.conf.js (1019 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/tsconfig.app.json (210 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/index.html (292 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/polyfills.ts (2835 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app.component.html (25757 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1062 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app.component.ts (211 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (640 bytes)
CREATE my-app1/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)

  Installing packages...
```

Comment: Did you stop the install and retry? May have been a one time issue.

Comment: i fixed it. just create your App in Node.js command prompt